# How can I implement nextjs Middleware for protected routes

Tags: authentication, next.js, routes

heres a simplified version I created so someone can help me, been stuck for a while now.

​

This is my home page, I have a button that routes to a page called redirect, it creates a cookie while routing:

```
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const login = (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("login");
    Cookies.set("currentUser", "true");
    router.push("/redirect");
  };

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <button onClick={(e) => login(e)}>click me</button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

​

Routes to this:

```
"use client";
import React from "react";

function page() {
  return <div>redirect</div>;
}

export default page;
```

​

Here's what I have so far in my middleware:

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

 
export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let currentUser = request.cookies.get('currentUser')?.value
 
  if (!currentUser) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
  }
}
```

It checks if the cookie exists, if it doesn't I want it to redirect back to the homepage. I do have the file (middleware.ts) in my root folder. Sadly it isn't working and I'm not sure why. Spent the whole afternoon on yt, documentation, etc. I'm just a casual programmer so pardon me if this is too easy to figure out.

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: You are not getting the cookie in the middleware, or it's not firing at all?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar the middleware isn’t working at all cause I can clear cookies and manually go to the /redirect route which shouldn’t happen if the middleware is working. I’m so confused.

Comment: I see. Do you have a `src` folder or not?